# akka remoting actor system does not start on remote machine

Tags: akka, remoting

I hit one strange issue in akka.remoting: when I run directly "java ..... com.Main", remoting was not started at remote machine, so remote actor system is not listening at configured port. But if I run in "sbt run", it does open the port and listen at it. What could be issue?

Here is console.log:
[dong@ftlxsvr02 pipelinemanager]$ **sbt run**

[info] Loading project definition from /mnt/fvg02vol8/PipelineManager/test/pipelinemanager/project
[info] Set current project to pipelinemanager (in build file:/mnt/fvg02vol8/PipelineManager/test/pipelinemanager/)
Multiple main classes detected, select one to run:

[1] com.pipelinemanager.Main
[2] com.pipelinemanager.RemoteActorSystem

Enter number: 2

[info] Running com.pipelinemanager.RemoteActorSystem
[DEBUG] [07/22/2016 09:27:39.502] [run-main-0] [EventStream(akka://RemoteSystem)] logger log1-Logging$DefaultLogger started
[DEBUG] [07/22/2016 09:27:39.504] [run-main-0] [EventStream(akka://RemoteSystem)] Default Loggers started
[INFO] [07/22/2016 09:27:39.615] [run-main-0] [akka.remote.Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [07/22/2016 09:27:39.868] [run-main-0] [akka.remote.Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://RemoteSystem@ftlxsvr02:9500]
[INFO] [07/22/2016 09:27:39.870] [run-main-0] [akka.remote.Remoting] Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://RemoteSystem@ftlxsvr02:9500]
[INFO] [07/22/2016 09:27:39.887] [run-main-0] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(RemoteSystem)] ## Remote Pipeline Manager App Started ##
Remote Pipeline Manager App Started....

**But when run in JAVA, it does not work:**

[dong@ftlxsvr02 pipelinemanager]$ java -classpath ./bin/pipelinemanager-0.0.6.jar com.pipelinemanager.RemoteActorSystem
Remote Pipeline Manager App Started....
[INFO] [07/22/2016 09:31:39.494] [main] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(RemoteSystem)] ## Remote Pipeline Manager App Started ##

**See the difference is following:**

[DEBUG] [07/22/2016 09:27:39.502] [run-main-0] [EventStream(akka://RemoteSystem)] logger log1-Logging$DefaultLogger started
[DEBUG] [07/22/2016 09:27:39.504] [run-main-0] [EventStream(akka://RemoteSystem)] Default Loggers started
[INFO] [07/22/2016 09:27:39.615] [run-main-0] [akka.remote.Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [07/22/2016 09:27:39.868] [run-main-0] [akka.remote.Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://RemoteSystem@ftlxsvr02:9500]
[INFO] [07/22/2016 09:27:39.870] [run-main-0] [akka.remote.Remoting] Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://RemoteSystem@ftlxsvr02:9500]
Any idea? SBT run behavior is what I need

The code to start actor system at remote machine:

...
`

```
object RemoteActorSystem{

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val fileName = "remotesystem.conf"

    val configFile = getClass.getClassLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile

    val config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(configFile))

    val remoteConfig = new RemotingConfig(fileName)

    val system = ActorSystem(remoteConfig.systemName, config)

    val defaultActor = system.actorOf(Props[RemoteActorSystem], 
                             remoteConfig.className)

    system.log.info("## Remote Pipeline Manager App Started ##")

  }
```

}`